# Unable to configure JSON in android studio

Tags: java, android, sql, asp.net, json

I'm working on a project. There is a website coded in asp.net and database is SQL. and there is a mobile app connect to this site.in app it used JSON and no db codes. I added new tables to this site and I want to configure it from android studio. I'm new to JSON so I can't config the database from android studio. And I want to know what is a .ashx file is? I can't add code snips due to privacy policy in company. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**.ashx file details:**

A file with the ASHX file extension is an ASP.NET Web Handler file that often holds references to other web pages used in an ASP.NET web server application.
The functions in the ASHX file are written in the C# programming language, and sometimes the references are so short that an ASHX file may end up just being a single line of code.
Most people only encounter ASHX files by accident when they try to download a file from a website, like a PDF file. This is because the ASHX file references the PDF file to send it to the browser for download but doesn't name it correctly, attaching .ASHX at the end instead of .PDF.
source: https://www.lifewire.com/ashx-file-2619693

And as far as I think for accessing JSON in the android studio you can look into volley.

**Volley Documentation:** https://developer.android.com/training/volley